# What is "clear all" Matlab equivalent for Python (Spyder)?

Tags: python

I just migrated to Python from Matlab. I would appreciate your support. Thank you for your time.

In Matlab, when I start a script I always begin with "clear all' to empty the workspace. I use Spyder - Python 3.8 (Anaconda Distribution). I would like to clear the variables in Variables Explorer window before I begin a script. Could you please suggest on how can I achieve this?

In [1], a similar question is asked, but that does not include "clear all" command. I presently use an option suggested in [2], which is given below. I would like to know if this the optimal way to do it or is there a better method.

```
from IPython import get_ipython;   
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
```

Reference:

1. [Python equivalent of Matlab's clear, close all, clc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215532/python-equivalent-of-matlabs-clear-close-all-clc)
2. [How do I clear all variables in the middle of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543833/how-do-i-clear-all-variables-in-the-middle-of-a-python-script)